# Can I run our tests using redgreen without changing our source code?

Tags: ruby, testing, rake, redgreen

I'd like to use redgreen (or similar) to colour the output of our tests, but I don't want to force it on everyone else.  Is there a way for me to use it without changing our source code?

Comment: Are you writing a gem, or an in-house project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code like this to your `test_helper.rb` to base it on your environment settings:

```
if ENV['REDGREEN']
  require 'redgreen'
end
```

If the project uses bundler, you'll need it in the Gemfile, but you can disable it by default:

```
gem "redgreen", :require => false
```

You can have redgreen always enabled in your own personal environment by adding it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or the appropriate file for your shell:

```
export REDGREEN=true
```